# What does |AM|=|AC| mean?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

What does $$|AM|=|AC|$$ mean?
$$AM$$ and $$AC$$ are rays.
Do they mean the length or what?

Comment: Yes, they mean the length.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, If $X$ and $Y$ are any two points in a euclidean space, then $|XY|$ means the distance between $X$ and $Y$, while $XY$ refers to the line segment between $X$ and $Y$ (inclusive). At one time, people would use the same notation, $XY$, for both meanings, leaving what is meant to be worked out from the context. It is recommended to use the modern and precise notation for clarity.